# Hosting a Wordpress blog subdomain on another server

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, subdomain, shared-hosting, add-on-domain

I wish to add a blog to my online store, but due to security issues with Wordpress and just for peace of mind to keep it away from my ecommerce site data, we want the blog hosted on another server/account. We have seen and heard of instances where a hacked WP has allowed access to the entire hosting account and therfore led to a hack on the non-WP site.

I suppose I want the reverse of Add-On domains, files hosted elsewhere but pointing to blog.myshop.com
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Addon+Domains#

How can I setup blog.myshop.com but have the blog hosted on another account/server?

Comment: Ask your host for a cPanel WHM account that allows creating additional accounts that are jailed from one another, add-on domains are not secure and you might as well not use a sub domain all together for that purpose. Alternatively options include purchasing a hosting else where and updating your DNS records with the cname 'blog'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486402/how-to-redirect-a-subdomain-to-another-website  this might help

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the blog getting compromised you can set up another account on another hosting provider. If you host your DNS with your main provider, which I am assuming you do, then you will need to set up an A record using the [Advanced Zone Editor](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Advanced+Zone+Editor).Point the A record to the new account IP address and start blogging.

I would suggest hosting the blog over at WordPress.com you can see how to map your subdomain to [their service](https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-subdomain/).